# Is it possible to read and/or write ports via a C variable instead of using GPIO_Pin_N values?

Tags: c, arm, stm32

All the sample code I can find accesses ports like so:

```
GPIO_SetBits(GPIOE, GPIO_Pin_9 | GPIO_Pin_13);
```

Which looked OK at first, until I tried to reference LEDs (my port E) by index (0-7). A `switch` or a LUT is a solution, but I don't like either. Is it possible to declare e. g. `uint8_t` and map it to the specific range of pins of a certain port?

Comment: Looks at the definition of `GPIO_SetBits`, you are free to access the registers directly.

Comment: Yes or no, depending on if your operation system allows it. That's why this extra layer of abstraction exists. If you don't care about that, then yes, you can: registers are addresses, you can directly write to them easily, usually.

Comment: @user3528438 Operating system? I think you're confused. STM32 is an embedded platform; there's no operating system present unless you bring one. :)

Comment: @duskwuff Well, this is not really a OS problem, but a MMU problem. I just found out STM32 does not have a MMU so yes, this problem does not exist. But FreeRTOS supports for STM32.

Comment: Does your particular device offer a bit-band alias of the GPIO registers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard Cortex-M3/M4 memory map allows for the CPU to have so-called "bit-band" aliases of regions, in which writing to each word in the bit-band alias performs an automatic read-modify-write to alter the target bit in the corresponding region.

Taking the STM32F411 (Cortex-M4F) manual I have to hand as an example, that shows the peripheral region `0x40000000-0x400FFFFF` is covered by a bit-band alias in the region `0x42000000-0x43FFFFFF`. Thus for instance on that device (if I've got my maths right) each word from `0x42420280-0x42420300` corresponds to a bit in the GPIO port E data register GPIOE_ODR at `0x40021014`, so this:

```
volatile int *leds = (void *)0x42420280;
leds[x] = 1; /* only bit 0 of the bit-band word actually holds data */
```

makes the hardware perform the tidily-abstracted equivalent of this:

```
volatile int *leds = (void *)0x40021014;
int val = *leds;
val |= (1 << x);
*leds = val;
```

If you have a suitable device, don't want to update multiple bits at once, and don't mind the extra overhead vs. a single access to the regular register in some cases (e.g. writing the set/clear registers instead of the data), it's a pretty neat trick.

Comment: This works well if the STM32 in question supports bit-banding, however only the Cortex-M3 and M4 parts implement bit-banding, not Cortex-M0 STM32's.

Answer (score 0):

The values of the `GPIO_Pin_X` constants are defined as bit positions within a 16-bit value, with pin 0 as the least significant bit and pin 15 as the most significant:

```
#define GPIO_Pin_0                 ((uint16_t)0x0001)  /*!< Pin 0 selected */
#define GPIO_Pin_1                 ((uint16_t)0x0002)  /*!< Pin 1 selected */
#define GPIO_Pin_2                 ((uint16_t)0x0004)  /*!< Pin 2 selected */
[...]
#define GPIO_Pin_15                ((uint16_t)0x8000)  /*!< Pin 15 selected */
```

(This is why you can OR them together to write to multiple pins!)

If you need to index pins dynamically, you can do so using a macro like:

```
#define GPIO_Pin(x) ((uint16_t) 1 << (x))
```

Comment: I guess OP is expecting `GPIO_Pin_4 = true;`. The reason that's not possible is that a group of pins are controlled by a wide register: like in this case, 16 pins are controlled by a 16-bit register. In order to set a few pins in this group, the function need to read the group, make changes to a few pins, and write the group back.

Comment: @user3528438 That's not entirely true. The STM32 GPIO peripheral has bit-set/reset registers (e.g, `GPIOA_BSRR`), which are used by `GPIO_SetBits()` to change pin state without a read/modify/write cycle.

Comment: This isn't an answer to my question.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe Then you need to explain more clearly what you're trying to do.

Comment: I have explained it quite clearly, see the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

busses are fixed width you cannot change that hardware with software, and no you cannot break up a fixed sized register in a peripheral into smaller parts with software.   You can possibly make it appear in software to do such a thing but in the end the real code generated by the high level code will still do read-modify-writes or whatever is needed or supported based on bus or peripheral register sized transactions.

Trying to make things smaller even making variables byte sized vs the native size of registers ultimately creates more or inefficient code.  So trying to understand why you would want to do such a thing anyway.

An stm32 I recently played with has a bit clear/set register where writing a one clears or sets the output state of a pin.  In the logic it simply clears or sets the flip flop controlling that port output, which in logic they can/do implement the backend of a control into smaller parts, but from software you cannot directly access those in non-aligned, not properly sized transfers.  Some companies require you, in software, to do a read-modify-write.  So using an stm32 with these kinds of features (other brands may also have similar features, sometimes using the address, sometimes like this but in separate registers one for setting one for clearing) actually makes your code about as simple as it can be.

You are more than welcome to create as many defines as you want for combinations of gpio pins so that in your main code you only need one mnemonic instead of multiples orred together if that is your desire.

You do not have to have a function for setting the bits if you can get the compiler to reliably generate a str of the right size, and the right combination if bits in a single define you can simply the code into an a = b; situation.

My guess from your vague question, is a LUT is the optimal solution.